# CSS Transform & transition

Tags: css, formatting, css-transitions, css-animations

I have an image and I need its on hover opacity to be 0.5, then It must scale up to 200% and back the opacity up to 1 when image is full scaled size.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/207PZ.png)

[image]

I am able to make a scaling transform and opacity on hover, but I need the opacity to be 1 after the scale when image is at 200% size.

```
#imagecontainer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 251px;
  height: 251px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
#image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
#image:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  -webkit-transform: scale(2, 2);
}
```

Comment: You have more than one state change and so you should animation instead of transition (or use some JS along with CSS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are more than one state change (that is, `opacity: 0.5` initially before the `transform` is completed and then `opacity: 1` after the transform is completed, you cannot do it with `transition` alone because the transition can only change the `opacity` value once and retain it. You either need to use CSS3 animations or alter the styling using JS with `transitionend` event.

Below is a sample snippet with CSS3 animations where on `hover` the image gets `opacity: 0.5` and this state is retained till the `99%` keyframe. All this happens while the image goes from not having any transform to `transform: scale(2,2)`. Then at the `100%` frame, the `transform` is retained as it is but `opacity` is changed from `0.5` to `1`.

```css
#imagecontainer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 251px;
  height: 251px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
#image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
}
#image:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  animation: opacitynscale 1s ease-in-out forwards;
}
@keyframes opacitynscale {
  99% {
    transform: scale(2, 2);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(2, 2);
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

```html
<div id='imagecontainer'>
  <img id='image' src='http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1' />
</div>
```

---

The downside of using CSS `animation` instead of `transition` for this is that unlike `transition`, the `animation` wouldn't automatically produce the reverse effect on hover out (that is, it would snap back to original state and not gradually go back). Another `animation` must be written for the reverse effect.

If you can't use CSS3 `animation` for whatever reasons (including the aforementioned) then you can do it with a bit of JavaScript by using the `transitionend` event.

```js
var img = document.getElementById('image'),
  mousein = false;

img.addEventListener('transitionend', function() { /* this event is fired when transition is over */
  if (mousein)
    img.style.opacity = 1; /* changes element's opacity to 1 */
  else
    img.style.opacity = null; /* remove inline style on hover out, otherwise it will override others */
});

/* to determine if mouse is over image or not */
img.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  mousein = true;
});
img.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  mousein = false;
});
```

```css
#imagecontainer {
  border: 2px solid red;
  width: 251px;
  height: 251px;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
#image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
#image:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: scale(2, 2);
}
```

```html
<div id='imagecontainer'>
  <img id='image' src='http://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1' />
</div>
```